# How to track a face that is 5m away from source in facial detection for matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

I am currently trying to figure out how to be able to detect a face that is 5m away from the source and will have its facial features clear enough for the user to see. The code i am working on is as shown.

```
faceDetector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector();

%Get the input device using image acquisition toolbox,resolution = 640x480 to improve performance

obj =imaq.VideoDevice('winvideo', 1, 'YUY2_640x480','ROI', [1 1 640 480]);
set(obj,'ReturnedColorSpace', 'rgb');
figure('menubar','none','tag','webcam');

   while (true)
    frame=step(obj);
    bbox=step(faceDetector,frame);


    boxInserter  = vision.ShapeInserter('BorderColor','Custom',...
    'CustomBorderColor',[255 255 0]);
videoOut = step(boxInserter, frame,bbox);

    imshow(videoOut,'border','tight');

    f=findobj('tag','webcam');

    if (isempty(f));
        [hueChannel,~,~] = rgb2hsv(frame);

% Display the Hue Channel data and draw the bounding box around the face.
figure, imshow(hueChannel), title('Hue channel data');


rectangle('Position',bbox,'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',1)
hold off
noseDetector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('Nose');
faceImage    = imcrop(frame,bbox);
imshow(faceImage)  
noseBBox     = step(noseDetector,faceImage);

noseBBox(1:1) = noseBBox(1:1) + bbox(1:1);
videoInfo    = info(obj);
ROI=get(obj,'ROI');
VideoSize = [ROI(3) ROI(4)];

videoPlayer  = vision.VideoPlayer('Position',[300 300 VideoSize+30]);
tracker = vision.HistogramBasedTracker;
initializeObject(tracker, hueChannel, bbox);

while (1)



% Extract the next video frame
    frame = step(obj);
% RGB -> HSV
    [hueChannel,~,~] = rgb2hsv(frame);

    % Track using the Hue channel data
    bbox = step(tracker, hueChannel);

    % Insert a bounding box around the object being tracked
    videoOut = step(boxInserter, frame, bbox);

    %Insert text coordinates

    % Display the annotated video frame using the video player object
    step(videoPlayer, videoOut);
    pause (.2)
end

% Release resources
release(obj);
release(videoPlayer);

        close(gcf)




        break
    end
    pause(0.05)
end
release(obj)
% remove video object from memory
        delete(handles.vid);
```

I am trying to work on this code to figure out the distance it can cover when tracking a face. I couldnt figure out which one handles that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is, but try this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/face-detection-and-tracking-using-live-video-acquisition.html). It uses the KLT algorithm, which, IMHO, is more robust for face tracking than CAMShift. It also uses the webcam interface in base MATLAB, which is very easy.